# How to check if byte array is valid UTF-8 String

Tags: java, arrays, byte, utf

I'm decoding messages with `javax.crypto.Cipher` and as an output I get `byte[]`. What is the **fastest** way to check if my key is correct and `byte[]` is valid string?

Comment: Getting a vaid UTF-8 string doesn't guarantee that the key is valid. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

Try This :-

```
public boolean checkUTF8(byte[] barr){

        CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(barr);

        try {
            decoder.decode(buf);

        }
        catch(CharacterCodingException e){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```